# How to extend IdentityManager for IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, .net, identity, identityserver3

I have IdentityServer 3 up and running with all Users, Roles, Claims, Clients etc running from the database.  To administer this I have decided to use IdentityManager.  I have noticed though that this only covers Users and Roles.  Is there a way to extend this to cover the Clients as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
[IdentityServer3.Admin](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin) or
[IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework)

I tried IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework it works fine for me.